# Angular 4 - creating input type dynamically with ngFor

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, angular-template, angular-forms

since I got a form with a lot of different input fields, to avoid having a gigantic html template I want to put the fields data inside objects and create the template dynamically using `ngFor`. 
This is my code until now.

**stub.ts** - this is where I store my data

```
export const MY_DATA = [
  { placeholder: 'First name', name: 'name', model: 'model.name'},
  { placeholder: 'Last name', name: 'lastName', model: 'model.lastName'},
  { placeholder: 'Age', name: 'age', model: 'model.age'}
];
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MY_DATA} from './stub';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-valutazione-insert',
  templateUrl: './valutazione-insert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./valutazione-insert.component.css']
})
export class ValutazioneInsertComponent implements OnInit {

  model: any = {};
  data = MY_DATA;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  submit() {
      console.log('Data submitted: ', this.model);
    }

}
```

**template.html**

```
<div id="datiRichiesta" [hidden]="datiRichiestaClicked" >
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let d of data">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{d.placeholder}}" [(ngModel)]=d.model name="{{d.name}}"
                onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" (blur)="this.placeholder = d.placeholder"/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**These are the input fields I got:**
[image]

**This is the rendered html code:**
[image]

Now, I got some things that don't work:

1. even if on the rendered html all attributes are correctly set, the placeholder value takes the model value
2. the behaviour of the placeholder `onfocus` and `onblur` is not working
3. most important, if I try to submit some values these are not passed to the controller

Now every problem disappear if I use an input type with all properties set statically. Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**stubs.ts**

It is better to renamed `model` to `modelPropName` to make it more clear.

This means `First name` will be set in the `name` property of the `model: any = {}` object, and so on.

```js
export const MY_DATA = [
  { placeholder: 'First name', name: 'name', modelPropName: 'name'},
  { placeholder: 'Last name', name: 'lastName', modelPropName: 'lastName'},
  { placeholder: 'Age', name: 'age', modelPropName: 'age'}
];
```

**template.html**

```html
<form id="datiRichiesta" [hidden]="datiRichiestaClicked" (submit)="submit()">
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let d of data">
        <input type="text" 
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="{{d.placeholder}}" 
            [(ngModel)]="model[d.modelPropName]"
            name="{{d.name}}"
            (focus)="$event.target.placeholder = ''" 
            (blur)="$event.target.placeholder = d.placeholder"/>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

When you submit the form you should in the console:

`Data submitted:  Object {name: "...", lastName: "...", age: "..."}`

Comment: This is simple and perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I want to create one but my object has 2 levels  {name: "...", lastName: "...", age: "...", 2level: {other: "...",other2:"..."}} Can be done?